# Error "The name "soap" does not denote a namespace" if i try to parse XML in T-sql

Tags: sql, xml

When i try to parse XML in T-sql I get error "The name "soap" does not denote a namespace"
This is my XML and query. Answer, please, how can I parse such XML. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml =
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
   <soap:Body>
      <GetWebLinkResponse xmlns=http://test.org/ xmlns:ns2=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration xmlns:ns3=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration.Results xmlns:ns4=http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/>
         <GetWebLinkResult>
            <ns3:Error>
               <ns2:Id>0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:Text>Success.</ns2:Text>
            </ns3:Error>
            <ns3:Url>
                    https://example.com&amp;content=true
                    </ns3:Url>
         </GetWebLinkResult>
      </GetWebLinkResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'      
 
 
SELECT
   -- n.value('(./Code/text())[1]','int') as CODE
--,
  n.value('ns3:Url','varchar(1000)')as NAME
FROM @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetWebLinkResponse/GetWebLinkResult') as a(n)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be quoting attribute values?

Comment: I not understand What do you mean "quoting attribute values"... could you explain how can I parse such XML in T-sql ? Where is my mystake? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your XML is invalid - your namespace definitions must be in double quotes:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml =
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetWebLinkResponse xmlns="http://test.org/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration.Results" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
         <GetWebLinkResult>
            <ns3:Error>
               <ns2:Id>0</ns2:Id>
               <ns2:Text>Success.</ns2:Text>
            </ns3:Error>
            <ns3:Url>
                    https://example.com&amp;content=true
                    </ns3:Url>
         </GetWebLinkResult>
      </GetWebLinkResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

Once you've corrected that, you'll need to define **all** relevant XML namespaces for your T-SQL query. Relevant XML namespaces are all explicitly used namespaces (like `soap:` and `ns3:`), as well as **default** namespaces like the `xmlns="http://test.org/"` on your `<GetWebLinkResponse>` node.

When you declare them all - the T-SQL query should work:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap, 
                   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration.Results' as ns3, 
                   DEFAULT 'http://test.org/')
    SELECT
        n.value('(ns3:Url)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS NAME
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetWebLinkResponse/GetWebLinkResult') as a(n)
```

Comment: Thank a lot, it`s really works correctly. I didn`t know such syntax with xml.  Expression with DEFAULT need to use always  ?

Comment: @kirkir: you need the `DEFAULT` clause **IF** your XML contains a **default** XML namespace..... (like `xmlns="http://test.org/"`)

Comment: Well, strictly you need to use the `DEFAULT` only if the XML contains a default and *you wish to use the same default in your XPath expression*. `WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS a, 
                   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.Configuration.Results' as b, 
                   'http://test.org/' as c)
    SELECT
        n.value('(b:Url)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS NAME
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('/a:Envelope/a:Body/c:GetWebLinkResponse/c:GetWebLinkResult') as a(n)` produces exactly the same result because it's the URIs that matter.